# Next post after a review audit

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits

Review audits are a great way to make users to concentrate on the task, because when they know that there are audits, users (including me) pay much attention.

But just after an audit, I always feel a relief kind of feel because I know that next audit won't popup for at least another 3 or 4 posts, and that's where the concentration level drops.

So I suggest that audits' randomness **should not have a minimum review limit** after a user have either passed or failed an audit. To be more clear, next post after an audit should also be an audit every once in a while.

Comment: Do you feel your concentration drops to where you aren't doing a good job reviewing or is it just that you're not hyper-vigilant about spotting an audit?

Comment: @yivi No, the system actually ensures that you don't get an audit for a certain number of reviews, I think it's 5, and the likelihood of one increases the longer you go without getting one, if memory serves (I'm less confident about the latter than the former).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Review audits are a great way to make users to concentrate on the
>   task, because when they know that there are audits, users (including
>   me) pay much attention.

If you are worrying about audits, in any way, then you are looking at reviewing the wrong way (a bit).

When reviewing, you evaluate the context and requirements before you and submit your educated decision. Whether this is an audit or real review shouldn't make any difference, in both cases you are simply reviewing the criteria you have based on your knowledge and understanding.

I get that audits keep people on their toes, but they shouldn't really be there for that, in my opinion they're mostly there to catch out robo reviewers. Either you feel you can do a review (audit or not) or you don't. If the latter you shouldn't be doing them, otherwise just do it :)

> But just after an audit, I always feel a relief kind of feel because I know that next audit won't popup for at least another 3 or 4 posts, and that's where the concentration level drops.

The concentration drop isn't ideal, and could mean either after an audit you are lacking in fair ability to do reviews and so shouldn't, or you are too hyped up before an audit occurs.

Just think of audits you pass as a sign you are doing things correctly, no relief needed - just confirmation you did well. If you get a failed audit, well that too is a good thing to let you know there is something you can tweak in your decision making, which in turn will help you make better decisions on real reviews.

Realistically one should be less scared of failing an audit than making a bad decision on a real review, because the later has real consequences.

> So I suggest that audits' randomness should not have a minimum review
>   limit after a user have either passed or failed an audit. To be more
>   clear, next post after an audit should also be an audit every once in
>   a while.

Users who don't mind audits would welcome this I guess, but given your "fear" of audits surely this would be a bad thing for you? You'd then just worry about every review potentially being an audit?

You just need to change the way you think about reviews. Relax about them and just give your opinion based on what is in front of you. There are tens of thousands of people reviewing on Stack Overflow, and plenty making bad decisions and not caring about what they click. Given your consideration towards not doing a bad job means you are likely in at least average or above of those who actually do a good job.